# polygonscan Verify & Publish Contract Source Code

Tags: ethereum, polygon, smartcontracts, remix

I used remix to rewrite erc721 contract and add some feature to it. my main contract import some sol file and the imported file import other sol file. I deployed main contract to polygon network. I can't verify & publish contract source code.I select single file with flatten file but it show not match to the list of compiled contract bytecode outputs.
[single file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSaDJ.png)
[not match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI7HH.png)

but when I select "Solidity (Single file)" and it show Compiler error, because that files what I import to main contract still import other files. Does anyone know how to upload whole project to Verify?

[Solidity (Single file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecG6g.png)
[Compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUM2G.png)